# Calculating $\lim_{x\to2^+}\frac{3x}{\ln(x-2)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to understand limits with natural logarithms:

$$\lim_{x\to2^+}\frac{3x}{\ln(x-2)}$$

Consider that $2^+$ is a "number that is slightly larger than $2$":

$$2^+ > 2$$

So we have that

$$2^+-2 = 0^+$$

That is, a number that is slightly larger than $0$.

Since we have a number greater than $0$ but obviously lower than $1$, the natural logarithm will result in a negative value. What happens the closer we get to $0$ from the right? The negative number gets more and more negative. In other words: $-\infty$.

So we have that

$$\frac{3\cdot2^+}{-\infty} = \frac{6}{-\infty} = 0$$

As any number divided by either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ will be $0$.

Is this correct?

Comment: In my opinion you are correct...........

Comment: Yeah, your thought process is correct. But just in case, be sure that by writing things like $\frac{6}{-\infty}$, you only mean it informally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heuristic reasoning in the OP is fine.  I thought it might be instructive to see a rigorous approach to showing that the limit is indeed $0$.

Note that for $2<x<3$, we have

$$\left|\frac{3x}{\log(x-2)}\right|<\frac{9}{-\log(x-2)}$$

Now, given any number $\epsilon>0$,

$$\frac{9}{-\log(x-2)}<\epsilon$$

whenever $0<x-2<e^{-9/\epsilon}$.

Therefore, we have that given any $\epsilon>0$

$$\left|\frac{3x}{\log(x-2)}\right|<\epsilon$$

whenever $0<x-2<\delta=\min\left(1,e^{-9/\epsilon}\right)$.  And this completes the proof!